# Problems with ASP.NET MVC Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, url

I'm just a beginner in **ASP.NET technologies** and a **starter about C#** though I've experiences over Apache and PHP.

Now, I'm on a project that use ASP.NET MVC. Although it works fine while using aps.net deployment server, I became just like a fool when I try to deploy over **IIS Server**. Honestly saying, I really did follow the instructions from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407.aspx).

So, anybody who can give any light to me, please ?
Really do I want a comprehensive manual(step-by-step) for deployment.
I'm using **IIS 5.1** and **ASP.net MVC 2.0** .

Thanks in Advance

[Waiyan]

Comment: Sorry for typemistake. ASP.NET Technologies.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the guide I used with IIS 6](http://www.asp.net/Learn/mvc/tutorial-08-vb.aspx), it should work just fine with IIS 5.